# Axios call not finishing execution

Tags: javascript, reactjs, axios

When making a request, I notice that the addPlayers function doesn't finish running, and in turn prevents joinGame from completing execution. My back-code works perfectly; when `Axios.post` in the async addPlayer function is called, it adds as it should to the database.

```
const addPlayer = async () => {
        try {
            console.log("addplayers");
            await Axios.post(`${baseURL}addPlayers`, {
                username: ign,
                socket_id: socket.id,
                code: code,
            });
            console.log("end of addPlayer");
            return Promise.resolve(1);
        } catch (error) {
            console.log(error);
        }
    };


const joinGame = async () => {
        try {
            await getGames();
            console.log("after getGames in joinGame");
            const isValidCode = codes.includes(code);
            const isValidIgn = list.every(player => player.name !== ign);

            if (isValidCode) {
                if (isValidIgn) {
                    setAdded(true);
                    setCodeFinal(code);

                    await addPlayer();
                    console.log("after addPlayers");
                    const getPlayerDataRes = Axios.get(`${baseURL}getInitialPlayerData`, {
                        socket_id: socket.id
                    });

                    let id2 = getPlayerDataRes.data.id;
                    console.log(id2);
                    setId(id2);
                    socket.emit("joingame", code, id, (response) => {
                        const names = response.players.map(player => player.name);
                        setOpps(names);
                    });
                } else {
                    console.log("Invalid ign");
                }
            } else {
                setCode("");
                console.log("Invalid code");
            }
        } catch (error) {
            console.log(error);
        }
    };
```

The code should finish executing but it doesn't. Something interesting I also noted is that on refresh, the error appears to be caught by the try/catch in the addPlayer function. What could be the problem?

Comment: Is there a reason you are not `await`ing this `const getPlayerDataRes = Axios.get(...)`?

Comment: Also, why is your async `addPlayer` function returning `Promise.resolve(1)`? Just return `1`, you already marked it as `async` so _by definition_ it returns a Promise already and the return _inside_ the function causes the promise to resolve.

Comment: @Mark just realized it should be awaiting, changed it.

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans I was debugging and changed it, but something I noticed is that the promise is never resolved — "end of addPlayer" isn't even printed.

Comment: Then the obvious observation is that you're waiting for Axios to finish a post, so: does it? Does that route ever finish (i.e. check your server code) or does it completely forget to send a response, keeping the HTTP(s) connection open for 600 seconds without sending any data back (or whatever your server's default connection time out is =), and thus keeping your post call in a suspected state for a _long_ time?

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans thank you! I completely overlooked that fact.